# Confusion with mathematical objects (sets and multisets in particular)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, multisets

The two sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,1,2,3\}$ are equal, but the two multisets $<1,2,3>$ and $<1,1,2,3>$ are not equal.

Multisets are generalizations of sets that allow repeated elements. A natural mapping exists from sets to multisets: we can write $\{1,2,3\} = <1,2,3>$ since these two objects have identical properties in all respects. Likewise,  $\{1,1,2,3\} = <1,1,2,3>$

So we have $$<1,1,2,3>  =\{1,1,2,3\} = \{1,2,3\} = <1,2,3>$$
But we noted that $<1,1,2,3> \neq <1,2,3>$, so we have a contradiction

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I wouldn't say we can write $\{1,1,2,3\}=<1,1,2,3>$ in this notation.

Comment: I wouldn't even say that $\{1,2,3\} = \langle 1,2,3 \rangle$. Those are different objects. If we look at how $\langle 1,2,3 \rangle$ is defined precisely, it's something different than $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @littleO But we don't always use the precise set-theoretic definition of equality for the symbol $=$.  e.g., you could use the same argument to say $2 \neq 2$, where the $2$ on the left is a natural number and the $2$ on the right is a real number (defined as a Dedekind cut). Is there something worse about this particular identification?

Comment: @JairTaylor In my mind, "equal" simply means "is". So "$a = b$" means that $a$ is actually the same object as $b$, not just that $a$ corresponds to $b$ under some isomorphism or something. When I do arithmetic with real numbers, I set things up in my mind in a way that the integers really are real numbers. So when I'm working with the real numbers, the symbol $2$ denotes the real number $1 + 1$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity for the real numbers, for example. (In other contexts the symbol $2$ might refer to something else.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a natural mapping from sets to multisets, but not all multisets are images of sets under this mapping. The mapping takes $\{1,2,3\}$ to the multiset $\{\!\{1,2,3\}\!\}$ in which each of the three elements occurs once, but it also takes the set $\{1,1,2,3\}$ to $\{\!\{1,2,3\}\!\}$, because the **set** $\{1,1,2,3\}$ also contains each of $1$, $2$, and $3$ exactly once: it is equal to the set $\{1,2,3\}$. The multiset $\{\!\{1,1,2,3\}\!\}$ is not the image of any ordinary set, because no ordinary set has two distinguishable copies of a single element.

A set is completely determined by its members, so if $A$ is a set, then (for instance) the number $1$ either is or is not a member of $A$: it can’t be a member twice or three times. Multisets are specifically designed to overcome this limitation: in a multiset we **can** have multiple instances of a single element, but when we do, we have a multiset that is not the natural counterpart of an ordinary set.

Thus, your example should read that the set $\{1,1,2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$ corresponds to (**not** is equal to) the multiset $\{\!\{1,2,3\}\!\}$.